# How to apply assumptions to pattern matching?

Tags: pattern-matching, assumptions

I'm trying to remove terms whose exponents are positive in a polynomial.
I tried this one;

```
Assuming[t > 0, x^t /. {x^a_ /; Positive@a -> 0}]
```

but the result becomes;

> x^t

I want to get 0 instead of this result.

How to do so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason Mathematica doesn't apply the assumption automatically, but you can enforce it like this:

```
Assuming[t > 0, x^t /. {x^a_ /; Simplify[Positive@a] -> 0}]
```

a minimal example:

```
Assuming[t > 0, t > 0]
(*t>0*)
```

```
Assuming[t > 0, Simplify[t > 0]]
(*True*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! If it is well-known thing, really sorry for taking your time.

Comment: I don't think it's well known and it would be interesting to know why mathematica behaves like this, it doesn't look like a bug.

Comment: Regarding automatic application: See the documentation of  [`Assuming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html#5081): It only affects functions with the [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) option, so you need [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) or similar ([`Positive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Positive.html) doesn't have the option).